# Spinner text center align both vertically and horizontally

Tags: android, android-spinner

I want to align text inside the spinner both vertically and horizontally centered. 
I am following the tutorial from [this site(first tutorial only).](http://nevescheng.blogspot.in/2013/05/spinner-with-item-text-aligned-to-center.html)

My problem is that android studio not able to find the `spinner_center_item` even though it is stored at location `\layout\spinner_center_item.xml`.

here is my code

```
menu = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.optionmenu, android.R.layout.spinner_center_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.spinner_center_item);
menu.setAdapter(adapter);
menu.setSelection(0);
```

here is my main xml code

```
 <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:entries="@array/optionmenu"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/setting"
        android:background="@drawable/button_border"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"  />
```

here is my code from \layout\spinner_center_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    />
```

here is my code from string.xml

```
 <string-array name="optionmenu">
        <item>Categories</item>
        <item>Calculator</item>
        <item>unit Converter</item>

    </string-array>
```

here is the error

```
C:\Users\Samvid\AndroidStudioProjects\SamsUltimateAllPurposeCalculator\app\src\main\java\com\sams\ultimateallpurpose\calculator\Main_Calculator.java
Error:(67, 120) error: cannot find symbol variable spinner_center_item
Error:(68, 57) error: cannot find symbol variable spinner_center_item
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the resource id of `spinner_center_item.xml` from this

```
android.R.layout.spinner_center_item
```

to this

```
R.layout.spinner_center_item
```

Here, `android.R` means you are trying find the `spinner_center_item.xml` from `android` package but its located in the `layout` folder.

Answer (score 3):

change your this code

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.optionmenu, android.R.layout.spinner_center_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.spinner_center_item);
```

from

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.optionmenu, android.R.layout.spinner_center_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_center_item);
```